# Can't Delete item in Android listView more than one time

Tags: android, eclipse, intellij-idea

When I select item in my listView and use longClick,

I want it to remove from my listView but after I delete for one

I can't delete other item so I need a help.

What did I do wrong ?? :: I think it about files[i] in if condition in the onItemLongClick

but for now I have no Idea at all..

```
public class Screen2 extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener {

    ListView listview1;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1;
    private File[] files;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.screen2);
        setupGUI();
        adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);


        File f = new File("/sdcard/");
        files = f.listFiles();
        for(File ff:files){
            if(ff.isFile() ==true){
                adapter1.add("file " + ff.getName());
            }
            else if(ff.isDirectory() == true){
                adapter1.add("Dir "+ ff.getName());
            }
        }

        listview1.setAdapter(adapter1);
        listview1.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);
    }

    public void setupGUI() {
        listview1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

        if (files[i].isFile() == true){

            String fname = "/sdcard/" + files[i].getName();
            AA.killSDFile(fname);
            AA.Msg(this, "file is removed", 0);


            adapter1.remove((String)adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i));

            Log.d("file:", fname+" is killed");
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to refresh the listview data by notifyDataSetChanged() function and need to recall this function on long press event

```
File f = new File("/sdcard/");
files = f.listFiles();
for(File ff:files){
    if(ff.isFile() ==true){
        adapter1.add("file " + ff.getName());
    }
    else if(ff.isDirectory() == true){
        adapter1.add("Dir "+ ff.getName());
    }
}

listview1.setAdapter(adapter1);
```

check this and pls let me know if you get any issue.